# Installing modules like pygal so they work in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, python-module, pygal

I'm a Python beginner working with Spyder, who must pip install modules for my class; pygal, for example. When I try to install, or reinstall as an administrator, this is what I get:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pygal
Requirement already satisfied: pygal in c:\users\flora\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (2.4.0)

Yet when I try to import the module in a Spyder file, this is the message I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\flora\crash python\data mining\world_population2.py", line 2, in 
    import pygal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygal'

And there's no sign of it in the dependencies in Spyder. Same thing using IDLE 3.8. I had assumed that Spyder or Anaconda would automatically be able to use it. Does it have something to do with WHERE I have saved it? I have tried reinstalling Anaconda, restarting my computer, etc. No difference.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to understand how to fix this problem.

Comment: Hi, Carlos: sounds like we're getting on the right track. But I don't know what this means, because to my knowledge, I didn't install either pygal or Spyder in a virtual environment, but in the most basic global way. Since first writing, I uninstalled, and installed pygal as an administrator at the command prompt, very simply with pip3 install pygal. So I don't understand how to even get to these first steps, pasted below:

Comment: This happens because foo was installed (with either conda or pip) in a different conda or venv/virtualenv environment than the one in which Spyder is currently running.

To confirm this is the problem, you need to:

Activate the environment (e.g. myenv) in which you installed the package foo (e.g. with source activate myenv on macOS/Linux or activate myenv on Windows, workon myenv for virtualenv/venv, etc)

Start a Python interpreter there by running the command python.

Comment: For those who want to know, the answer was a conda install, and I am now able to access pygal globally. Some of the software I was instructed to look for was out of date, but as PurpleLLama suggested below, pygal_maps_world now has most of what I needed. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No idea if this will help but if you goal is to use pygal you can try using a different ide with python build in. It does not run the most current version of python by default but you can change it to the version of python you have installed.
Try using [Thonny](https://thonny.org/) I was able to import and run some code from pygal.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I'm aware that SO is mostly for coding questions, but I'm really stuck. I'll try Thonny -- hope I'll be able to use other modules with it, too. :D

Comment: I used Thonny -- still no go. Pygal itself is not vital, but I'm concerned about installing other modules.

Comment: Go to Tool >> Mangage packages and then search for pygal. It should let you install very easily. You do need to spell the lib exactly right or it will not show when you search for it.

Comment: If it does not work I know another way to install it.

Comment: Hooray and rock and roll, PurpleLlama! I installed, and to be certain, I restarted my computer, and now import pygal does not throw an error message. However.... the specific module the book says to ask for (it's actually supposed to be this, rather than just import pygal)  from pygal.i18n import COUNTRIES. throws the following error: from pygal.i18n import COUNTRIES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygal.i18n' Maybe the book is out of date (it's only 2016). Or do I have to install this specifically, too? Thanks so far though!

Comment: It seems your book is out of date install pygal_maps_world

Comment: Hi, moving to chat now

Comment: Whoops, I don't have enough reputation to chat. However, it's saying there's no pygal_maps_world, which I suppose I have to install separately. Anyway thank you for trying Purple LLama